# Confirm dialogs for non-delete actions - bootbox-rails - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to delete a user from the system using this code:

```
<%= link_to fa_icon("minus-square", text: t('systems.delete')), doctor_path(doctor[:id]), method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('systems.confirm_delete') } %>
```

it says

> Are You Sure you want to delete this?

this works perfectly :).

but when I click finish button which is not delete, the message does not appear, but if I click finish button double, it work. 
Here my problem is, how can I enable when finish button pressed, I want to see message like "Are you sure?"

```
<%= f.submit t('finish'), class: "btn red button-next", id:"bitir_button", data: { confirm: "Süreci bitirmek istediğinize emin misiniz?" }
```

-

```
 $.rails.confirm = function(message, element) 
   { 

    var state = element.data('state');
    var txt = element.text();
    if (!state)
    {
        element.data('state', 'last');
        element.text('Are You Sure you want to delete this?');
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            element.data('state', null);
            element.text(txt);
        }, 10000);
        return false;
    }   
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
   };

   $.rails.allowAction = function(element) 
   {
    var message = element.data('confirm'),
        answer = false, callback;
    if (!message) { return true; }

    if ($.rails.fire(element, 'confirm')) 
    {
        // le extension.
        answer = $.rails.confirm(message, element);
        callback = $.rails.fire(element, 'confirm:complete', [answer]);
    }
    return answer && callback;
   };

   $.rails.handleLink = function(link) 
   {
    if (link.data('remote') !== undefined) 
    {
        $.rails.handleRemote(link);
    } 
    else if (link.data('method')) 
    {
        $.rails.handleMethod(link);
    }

    return false;
   };
```

Comment: What version of Rails is this? Rails 4+ includes `jquery_ujs` by default which will handle data-confirm dialogs.

Comment: I use Rails 4.2.2. as default data-confirm exist but I do not want to use. I tried this gem which is similar. I still use data-confirm to use this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bootbox-rails` to your gemfile.

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'bootbox-rails'
```

Override the rails confirm handler.

```
$.rails.confirm = function(message){
  return window.bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    return result;
  });
}
```

Comment: When I tested this clicking the cancel button in the dialog did not work - don't know if it's a bug in bootstrap or bootbox. The other options (x, esc or clicking outside) did work.